# how to write setting in form of JSON?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write following settings in form od JSON:

```
index : 
    analysis : 
        analyzer : 
            myAnalyzer2 : 
                type : custom 
                tokenizer : myTokenizer1 
                filter : [myTokenFilter1, myTokenFilter2] 
                char_filter : [my_html] 
        tokenizer : 
            myTokenizer1 : 
                type : standard 
                max_token_length : 900 
        filter : 
            myTokenFilter1 : 
                type : stop 
                stopwords : [stop1, stop2, stop3, stop4] 
            myTokenFilter2 : 
                type : length 
                min : 0 
                max : 2000 
        char_filter : 
              my_html : 
                type : html_strip 
                escaped_tags : [xxx, yyy] 
                read_ahead : 1024
```

please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, it was pretty much in JSON format all it needed was commas and curly braces

```
{ index : 
    { analysis : 
       { analyzer : 
           { myAnalyzer2 : 
               { type : custom, 
                tokenizer : myTokenizer1,
                filter : [myTokenFilter1, myTokenFilter2],
                char_filter : [my_html]}},
        tokenizer : 
           { myTokenizer1 : 
              {  type : standard,
                max_token_length : 900 }},
        filter : 
           { myTokenFilter1 : 
               { type : stop, 
                stopwords : [stop1, stop2, stop3, stop4]}, 
             myTokenFilter2 : 
               { type : length,  
                min : 0, 
                max : 2000 }},
        char_filter : 
             { my_html : 
               { type : html_strip, 
                escaped_tags : [xxx, yyy], 
                read_ahead : 1024}}
        }
    }
};
```